# gluon scene builder 8.3.0 line chart not a compound widget

Tags: javafx, gluon

I have recently migrated to the Gluon version of the JavaFX SceneBuilder app (v8.3.0) and note that it does not support the LineChart widget as a compound widget like is done with the Oracle version of SceneBuilder v2.0.

With the Oracle version, the LineChart widget can be expanded to show any axis widgets that have been added to the LineChart.

Anyone have any tips as to why this is so? Is it a bug? How are bugs reported for the Gluon version?

Comment: You are right, the CategoryAxis and NumberAxis doesn't show up in Gluon SB. I am not sure if there was a reason for this but you can report a bug [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues).

Comment: The `xAxis` and `yAxis` properties in the Scene Builder project at the OpenJFX [repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u/rt/file/25232792bc69/apps/scenebuilder/SceneBuilderKit/src/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/kit/metadata/util/DesignHierarchyMask.java#l128) use capital letters (`XAxis` and `YAxis`). Just changing that to initial lower letters fixes the issue.