# JavaFX chart in gluon's scene builder not displaying CategoryAxis or NumberAxis

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

The CategoryAxis and NumberAxis for all charts is no longer visible in Gluon's Scene builder. Is there a fix within scene builder for this? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477939/gluon-scene-builder-8-3-0-line-chart-not-a-compound-widget). It has been fixed already so it will be available in the next release.

Comment: Thanks for the update.